# Sounds in SoundPool does not load in android

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I am having problems loading sounds for my game. Or, rather, some of the sounds. It seems to have no problem loading `R.raw.success` and  `R.raw.fail`. but none of the notes will be loaded. The following is my load code:

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);  
int[] sounds = new int[6];        
sounds[0] = soundPool.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.note_c, 1);  
sounds[1] = soundPool.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.note_d, 1);  
sounds[2] = soundPool.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.note_e, 1);  
sounds[3] = soundPool.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.note_g, 1);  
sounds[4] = soundPool.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.note_a, 1);  
sounds[5] = soundPool.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.note_ctwo, 1);  
success_sound = soundPool.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.success, 1);  
fail_sound = soundPool.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.fail, 1);
```

It does not seem to matter which order i load the files. Only `fail` and `success` is loaded without problem. Sound was working for a good while, but during the last patch I'm working on, the sounds stopped loading. Changing name of the files did not resolve this either.

Have already tried extensively "googling" the errors in all ways shapes and forms, to no avail. I get the the following output in LogCat: (The two last lines are the success and fail sounds loading without problem.)

```
com.example.application E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
com.example.application E/NdkMediaExtractor: sf error code: -1010
com.example.application E/SoundPool: Unable to load sample
com.example.application E/NdkMediaExtractor: sf error code: -1010
com.example.application E/SoundPool: Unable to load sample
com.example.application E/NdkMediaExtractor: sf error code: -1010
com.example.application E/SoundPool: Unable to load sample
com.example.application E/NdkMediaExtractor: sf error code: -1010
com.example.application E/SoundPool: Unable to load sample
com.example.application E/NdkMediaExtractor: sf error code: -1010
com.example.application E/SoundPool: Unable to load sample
com.example.application E/NdkMediaExtractor: sf error code: -1010
com.example.application E/SoundPool: Unable to load sample
com.example.application I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
com.example.application I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
```

When the sound is **supposed** to be played, I get the following output:
`W/SoundPool: sample 1 not READY`

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with your assets (audio files)

I had the same issue (`E/NdkMediaExtractor: sf error code: -1010`) for some of my video files (.mov) on LG G4 device. (No problems on devices like Samsung S7, Huawei P9)

After converting all files with:

```
for f in *.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy -movflags +faststart "${f%.mov}.mp4"; done
```

Video files loaded correctly everywhere.

So, my suggestion to you: try to play with your audio files format - converting them to something else might help.